# Linking Custom Objects together in CRM using an API call

Tags: c#, rest, dynamics-crm

Created a custom entity (rooms) that can have a N:N relationship with itself and wanted to know if it was possible to link new instances of my room entity together in Dynamics CRM through an API Call?

Comment: you have mentioned API call and you have tagged c#, do you wish to achieve this wil c# code or using Javascript? as mostly API call is been done using front end (Javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an AssociateRequest:

```
public void AssociateEntities(IOrganizationService service, List<Entity> secondaryEntities, Entity primaryEntity, string relationshipName)
{
    AssociateRequest request = new AssociateRequest
    {
        Relationship = new Relationship(relationshipName),
        Target = primaryEntity.ToEntityReference(),
        RelatedEntities = new EntityReferenceCollection(secondaryEntities.Select(x => x.ToEntityReference()))
    };

    OrganizationResponse response = service.Execute(request);
}
```

Comment: So in this example would room A would be the primary entity and would the be linked to a list of new secondary entities?

Comment: So associating Room A with Room B and so on?

Comment: Correct, if you are only associating Room A to Room B, then the secondaryEntities list would just have a single record for Room B.

Comment: last thing, I am struggling with creating a service to pass into this method, any tips or links??

Comment: https://crmbook.powerobjects.com/extending-crm/plug-in-development-and-workflow-extensions/plug-ins/developing-a-plug-in/